# Node Express - empty query after form submit

Tags: forms, node.js, express

I would like to pars url after form submit.
I have simple form:

> ```
> form(method='post', action='/recipe/create')
>   hr
>     div
>       div.input.text
>         label(for='recipeTitle') Tytuł przepisu:
>         input(type='text', name='recipeTitle', id='recipeTitle')
>       div.input.text
>         label(for='photoFileName') Nazwa zdjęcia:
>         input(type='text', name='photoFileName', id='photoFileName')
> ```

After submit this code is executed.

```
exports.create = function(req, res){
   var url = require('url'); 
   var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);   
   console.log(url_parts);
```

My question is why console shows empty query

```
{ protocol: null,
  slashes: null,
  auth: null,
  host: null,
  port: null,
  hostname: null,
  hash: null,
  search: '',
  query: {},
  pathname: '/recipe/create',
  path: '/recipe/create',
  href: '/recipe/create' }
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you're posting to an URL which doesn't have a query string - `/recipe/create`.

Also, you seem to be using Express, which will give you the current query string already parsed:

```
// GET /search?q=tobi+ferret
req.query.q
// => "tobi ferret"

// GET /shoes?order=desc&shoe[color]=blue&shoe[type]=converse
req.query.order
// => "desc"

req.query.shoe.color
// => "blue"

req.query.shoe.type
// => "converse"
```

[Reference](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query)

Comment: Thanks for respond but is there any way to intercept data from submited form?

Comment: The form data will be available under [`req.body`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.body)

Comment: Yes, I realised that after my comment :). My point is that when i would like to add dynamicly fields to a form this is not so easy

Comment: You can use `Object.keys(req.query)` which returns an array of all the available properties on your object. No need to know them. You the just need to loop though the array. It looks something like this:
`Object.keys(req.query).forEach(query => {
    console.log(req.query[query]);
}